# javafx binding circle with Text so when I move the circle the Text moves with it

Tags: javafx

When I move the circle the text is not relocated.

Here is my code:

```
Text t = new Text(x,y, "HELLO");
Circle c = new Circle(x,y,radius);

t.xProperty().bind(c.centerXProperty());
t.yProperty().bind(c.centerYProperty());
```

Complete code:

```
package netfx;  



import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextBoundsType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

class RouterView  extends Group {
    private String name;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double radius;




    public void Routerview() {

    }
    RouterView(String n, double x, double y, double r){
        this.name = n;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = r;


    }


}
```

---

```
class LinkView {
    private String name;
    private RouterView src;
    private RouterView dst;


    public void EdgeView() {
    }
    public void EdgeView(String name, RouterView s, RouterView d) {
        this.name = name;
        this.src = s;
        this.dst = d;
    }
}
```

---

```
 public class NetFX extends Application {    
    Circle circle_Red, circle_Green, circle_Blue;
    double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
    double orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;



    HashMap<String, RouterView> routers = new HashMap<String, RouterView>();
    HashMap<String, LinkView> links = new HashMap<String, LinkView>();
    HBox hBox = new HBox(); 
    Group root = new Group();



    public String getRouterName(String msg){
        TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog(" Router Name ");
        dialog.setTitle("Router Name");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Topology manager");
        dialog.setContentText(msg);
        Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();         

            if (result.isPresent()){
                return result.get();
            }
            return null;         

    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {     
        hBox.setSpacing(10.0);
        Button addBtn  = new Button("ADD NODE");
        addBtn.setOnAction((event) -> { 
            String name = getRouterName("Enter Router Name: ");
            if (name != null) {
                AddRouter(name, 300,300,60);                             
                primaryStage.show();
            }
        });

        Button delBtn  = new Button("ADD EDGE");
        delBtn.setOnAction((event) -> { 
            String sname = getRouterName("Enter Source Router: ");
            RouterView sp = routers.get(sname);
            System.out.println(sname+" = "+sp);
            if (sp != null) {
                String dname = getRouterName("Enter Destination Router: ");
                RouterView dp = routers.get(dname);
                System.out.println(dname+" = "+dp);
                if (dp != null) {
                    //EdgeView e = AddEdge(sp,dp);
                    //edges.put(sname+"-"+dname,e);
                    primaryStage.show();
                }
            }
        });



        Button saveBtn = new Button("SAVE TOPOLOGY");                
        Button exitBtn = new Button("EXIT");
        exitBtn.setOnAction((event) -> { System.exit(0);});


        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(0, 20, 10, 20)); 
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(addBtn,delBtn,saveBtn, exitBtn);                        
        root.getChildren().addAll(hBox);         
        //primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400,350));         
        primaryStage.setTitle("TOPOLOGY MANAGER");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    public void AddRouter(String name, double x, double y, double r){       
        RouterView router = new RouterView(name,x,y,r);
        Circle c = new Circle(r, Color.GREEN);        
        c.setCenterX(x);
        c.setCenterY(y);
        Text t = new Text(x-10, y, name);                          
        c.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler);
        c.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);
        c.centerXProperty().bind(t.xProperty());
        c.centerYProperty().bind(t.yProperty());  

        root.getChildren().addAll(c,t);
        routers.put(name,router);    
    }


    public void AddEdge(){

    }


    EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMousePressedEventHandler =  new 
    EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
            orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
            orgTranslateX = ((Circle)(t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
            orgTranslateY = ((Circle)(t.getSource())).getTranslateY();
            System.out.println("orgSceneX = "+orgSceneX);
            System.out.println("orgSceneY = "+orgSceneY);
            System.out.println("orgTranslateX = "+orgTranslateX);
            System.out.println("orgTranslateY = "+orgTranslateY);
        }
    };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler =   new 
    EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
            double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
            double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
            double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;
            System.out.println("offsetX = "+offsetX);
            System.out.println("offsetY = "+offsetY);
            System.out.println("newTranslateX = "+newTranslateX);
            System.out.println("newTranslateY = "+newTranslateY);

            ((Circle)(t.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
            ((Circle)(t.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);            
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Given this code, if the circle changes its `xProperty` or `yProperty`, the text will move. If it's not working, something else is wrong in the code you haven't posted. Create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Depending on what you actually want to achieve it might be an alternative to put the Circle and the Text into a Group and then just move the Group arroung.

Comment: Note that the first code snippet you provided is different to the full code. You should bind the text coordinates to the circle center (as in the first snippet), not the circle center to the text coordinates (as in the full code).

Answer (score 0):

The location of the text is bound to the `centerX` and `centerY` properties of the circle. However, when you move the circle, you don't change those properties: you move it by changing the `translateX` and `translateY` properties.

Change the `centerX` and `centerY` properties, instead of the `translateX` and `translateY` properties:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMousePressedEventHandler = t -> {
    orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
    orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
    orgTranslateX = ((Circle)(t.getSource())).getCenterX();
    orgTranslateY = ((Circle)(t.getSource())).getCenterY();
    System.out.println("orgSceneX = "+orgSceneX);
    System.out.println("orgSceneY = "+orgSceneY);
    System.out.println("orgTranslateX = "+orgTranslateX);
    System.out.println("orgTranslateY = "+orgTranslateY);

};

EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler = t -> {
    double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
    double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
    double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
    double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;
    System.out.println("offsetX = "+offsetX);
    System.out.println("offsetY = "+offsetY);
    System.out.println("newTranslateX = "+newTranslateX);
    System.out.println("newTranslateY = "+newTranslateY);

    ((Circle)(t.getSource())).setCenterX(newTranslateX);
    ((Circle)(t.getSource())).setCenterY(newTranslateY);            

};
```